# Android layout/view to display swipe images

Tags: android, layout, view

what Android layout or view type to be used to create horizontally swipeable images. What I am after is like what is used by a lot of app when we firstly install it or when it was just updated. Usually app uses this type of view to explain some main features of the app.

Hopefully I am making sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use android ViewPager.
Visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's as I suspected ... just need some confirmation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ViewPager class to implement this feature. Check out the tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use coverflow to show swipable images with good animation that is more good than view pager only.

https://github.com/Polidea/android-coverflow